# Can I build an android app that can open, edit, and save Microsoft Word files in .doc and .docx formats?

Tags: ms-office

I want to build office suite for android for reading & editing MS office files.
I came across http://poi.apache.org/ - Java API for Microsoft Documents.                                                                                             But not sure how exactly I can use it inside the App. Can anybody share tutorials for implementing this library? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you find the solution? Please share.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you do so? There are already many different office suites on the Android market. Ok, all of them but SoftMaker Office Mobile produce formatting losses when opening Microsoft Office files, but if huge companies such as Google don't get it right, why should you?

My recommendation is downloading the free trial of SoftMaker's word processor "TextMaker Mobile", it's enormously feature-packed and lets you work with doc and docx formats seamlessly without formatting losses.

Comment: Thank You for recommendation, but want to try it & provide some operations with docx inside my App instead of using whole suite.